# Организация работы ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Написал код который реализует producer consumer паттерн c помощью `ConcurrentQueue<T>`(необходима именно fifo).
Меня смущает то как я решил эту задачу, прошу Вас указать на нюансы и показать как бы Вы реализовали это.

```
class Program
{
    static bool DestroyThread = false;
    static ConcurrentQueue<int> MyQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    static AutoResetEvent AutoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static Thread MyThread = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadWork));
        MyThread.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            MyQueue.Enqueue(i);
            AutoResetEvent.Set();
        }

        DestroyThread = true;
        AutoResetEvent.Set();
    }

    static void ThreadWork()
    {
        while (!DestroyThread)
        {
            if (MyQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                int temp;
                MyQueue.TryDequeue(out temp);
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            else
                AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Конкретно смущает `if (MyQueue.Count > 0)` такое чувство, что можно сделать более элегантно.

Comment: Почитайте приведенную ссылку, там есть реализации на С#